# In what date format does the mysql date datatype return data?

Tags: php, mysql, date

So, I have a date stored in MySQL with the `date` datatype and when I come to calling

```
echo $row_myRecordset['date']; // dreamweaver generated
```

in which date format will it return the date (eg. `yy-mm-dd`) so I can use it with moment.js?

Comment: see [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is readily available in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is yyyy-mm-dd, e.g. `2013-07-21` (see the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date))

Comment: Correct answer but irrelevant reference. The link you've posted relates to the `DATE` function, not the `DATE` type. A correct reference would be the second paragraph here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

It will return `YYYY-MM-DD` with the date datatype

Answer (score 0):

Should be YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

see: [http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Format_dates_stored_in_MySQL-16641.html](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2137313)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is **moment.js** the type of tuple used for mySQL to represent the date is of type DATE. You could read on the  [MySQL documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html)

All depending on how you are getting the data back from the page you can manipulate the data to format it however you want it, hence that "special" formatting that could be applied in that Javascript file **moments.js**. So if I don't see how you manipulate the date in that specific file, I can't really help you. Please post some code.

Also : This shows lack of research ! Look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944368/mysql-date-format?rq=1) 
 explained here on stackoverflow.com